How to have children route in Angular mfe?
I want to have child routes in loadRemoteModule, like below. How can achieve this?
const routes: Routes = [
  {  path: 'ParentContainer', loadComponent: () => loadRemoteModule({type: "module", remoteEntry: 'someRemoteEntry', exposedModule:"./ParentComponent"}),
    children:
    [
       { path: 'ChildContainer', loadComponent: () => loadRemoteModule({type: "module", remoteEntry: 'someRemoteEntry', exposedModule:"./ChildComponent"}) }
    ]
  ]

